# OS data hub data failing-access denied

Tags: qgis, wms, basemap

I am getting an error when I use the OS data hub WMS add layer option. QGIS accepts the connection and loads the layers but then when I zoom in or move, it comes up with an error saying 'Access denied: Forbidden'?

I have tried adding it in again etc and creating a new project API in OS data hub. I am using the OS map API function. Working in UK on CRS EPSG: 27700

Comment: Can you check what URL is being used by the refused request in the network logger plugin. I sounds like it is losing your API key

Comment: OS is pretty quick with support you can reach out to them to help resolve your issue  https://osdatahub.os.uk/support